# state machine - what is the best practice to log transitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

I am using state_machine gem and I'd like to store every state transition.

Is it just a matter of creating a new model called MyClassTransition with a transition:string from_state:state ? and add new record in that the new table on transition?

Is there a better practice to store these transition? I need a kind of a log ...

Any recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inventing this yourself, why don't you look at something like papertrail. This is what we use to record all our changes and it allows you to rollback.

There's a great tutorial on Railscasts:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-papertrail

Comment: I have question though. How do I check the attribute of the versioned objects. Do I need to reify? I want to check current object attributs with last version

Comment: No, you can inspect a version. Give me a few mins and I'll dig something out.

Comment: Sorry, laptop died. If you have papertrail on, you can inspect a version using something like: Model.find(x).versions.last.inspect - that shows the gist. You should be able to derive from that the information you need? You can also use Model.find(x).versions.last.object which gives you a lot of information. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to have a look at this: https://github.com/wvanbergen/state_machine-audit_trail

Unlike Papertrail, it only log the state attribute and doesn't support rollback/undo/revert. If you don't need a rollback, it's more simpler.

And sometimes you're using before/after_transition callbacks that affect other models, you can't leverage Papertrail's rollback system.